# Abandoned Mutex Exception on a Multithread TCP Server

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I am creating a multithread server and I am using mutex to control the sending data, the problem is when a client disconnect all the others clients also disconnect.

This is the server code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Pastel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeepestSwordServer
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static TcpListener server;
        public static TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        public static Thread t;
        public static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "poligamerMod");
        public static List<Connection> list = new List<Connection>();
        public static Connection con;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ConfigPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "config.json");

            if (File.Exists(ConfigPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Server...".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(165, 229, 250)));

                try
                {
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(ConfigPath);

                    Config config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(json);

                    Start(config.Ip, config.Port);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed To Start Server Error: {e.Message}".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Config File...".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(165, 229, 250)));

                Config config = new Config();
                config.Ip = "0.0.0.0";
                config.Port = 3878;

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);

                File.Create(ConfigPath).Dispose();
                File.WriteAllText(ConfigPath, json);

                Console.WriteLine("File Created!".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(58, 255, 0)));

                Console.WriteLine("Please see the config.json where is the ip, port and password if needed of the server, you need to restart the server!".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(165, 229, 250)));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static void Start(string ip, int port)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server Ready!".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(58, 255, 0)));
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                con = new Connection();
                con.stream = client.GetStream();
                con.streamr = new StreamReader(con.stream);
                con.streamw = new StreamWriter(con.stream);

                con.username = con.streamr.ReadLine();
                con.id = con.streamr.ReadLine();

                Event @event = new Event();

                @event.EventType = EventType.Join;
                @event.Username = con.username;
                @event.Id = con.id;

                string join = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);

                foreach (Connection c in list)
                {
                    c.streamw.WriteLine(join);

                    @event = new Event();

                    @event.EventType = EventType.Join;
                    @event.Username = c.username;
                    @event.Id = c.id;

                    string newJoin = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);

                    con.streamw.WriteLine(newJoin);
                }

                list.Add(con);

                @event = new Event();
                @event.EventType = EventType.List;

                foreach (Connection c in list.ToList())
                {
                    @event.List.Add(c.username, c.id);
                }

                string playerList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);

                con.streamw.WriteLine(playerList);

                Console.WriteLine($"{con.username} with id {con.id} has connected!".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(58, 255, 0)));

                t = new Thread(HearConnection);
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void HearConnection()
        {
            Connection hcon = con;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Connection c in list.ToList())
                    {
                        mutex.WaitOne();
                        c.streamw.WriteLine(hcon.streamr.ReadLine());
                        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    list.Remove(hcon);

                    Event @event = new Event();
                    @event.EventType = EventType.Leave;
                    @event.Username = con.username;
                    @event.Id = con.id;

                    string leave = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event);

                    foreach (Connection c in list)
                    {
                        c.streamw.WriteLine(leave);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"{hcon.username} with id {hcon.id} has disconnected!".Pastel(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)));

                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }

        public struct Connection
        {
            public NetworkStream stream;
            public StreamWriter streamw;
            public StreamReader streamr;
            public string username;
            public string id;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the important parts of the client code

```
public void Connect()
{
    MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
    MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Connecting...";

    try
    {
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(Ip.GetComponent<InputField>().text), Convert.ToInt32(Port.GetComponent<InputField>().text));

        if (client.Connected)
        {
            t = new Thread(Listen);

            stream = client.GetStream();
            streamw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            streamr = new StreamReader(stream);

            streamw.AutoFlush = true;

            streamw.WriteLine(Username);
            streamw.WriteLine(Id);

            t.IsBackground = true;

            t.Start();

            StartCoroutine(Yes());
        }
        else
        {
            MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Cant Connect To Server!";
            MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
            StartCoroutine(No());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo(e.Message);
        MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Cant Connect To Server!";
        MultiPlayerSubMenu.transform.GetChild(2).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
        StartCoroutine(No());
    }
}

public void Listen()
{
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = streamr.ReadLine();

            DoEvent(message);

            Logger.LogInfo(message);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                LostConnection = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogError(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that the others clients dont disconnect if one client disconnect.

Comment: Few things wrong with your code. **1)** it's a bit of a bad practice to do a catch-all via `catch (Exception ex)` because that implies your code can handle **all** types of exceptions including but not limited to _invalid operations; memory faults; thread issues;_ and of course _I/O exceptions_. Either `throw` them on or limit your `catch` to those exceptions you can really handle **2)** the code in your `catch` handler assumes there is nothing wrong with `c.stream` which is a bad assumption if it represents I/O during a faulty connection...

Comment: ... **3)** why the `Mutex` in an app targeting _multiple threads_?  Mutexs are for the synchronisation of multiple processes.  For an app designed to be a "singleton" process but with multiple threads, C#'s equivalent for a Critical Section is a better choice, say a simple `lock(_someObject)`.  **4)** whilst multiple threads can be handy for compute operations, they are not well-suited to I/O-bound code because they will spend the majority of their life waiting for I/O to complete.  **5)** using one thread per client sadly won't scale and can hurt the OS.  Try `async/await` instead.